# How to load only specific weights on Keras

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a trained model that I've exported the weights and want to partially load into another model.
My model is built in Keras using TensorFlow as backend.

Right now I'm doing as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, trainable=False))
model.add(Activation('relu', trainable=False))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), trainable=False))
model.add(Activation('relu', trainable=False))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), trainable=True))
model.add(Activation('relu', trainable=True))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.load_weights("image_500.h5")
model.pop()
model.pop()
model.pop()
model.pop()
model.pop()
model.pop()


model.add(Conv2D(1, (6, 6),strides=(1, 1), trainable=True))
model.add(Activation('relu', trainable=True))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I'm sure it's a terrible way to do it, although it works.

How do I load just the first 9 layers?

Comment: Seems `model.pop()` is not valid for modern Keras Model.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If your first 9 layers are consistently named between your original trained model and the new model, then you can use `model.load_weights()` with `by_name=True`.  This will update weights only in the layers of your new model that have an identically named layer found in the original trained model.

The name of the layer can be specified with the `name` keyword, for example:

```
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu',name='dens_1'))
```

Comment: By consistently named, you mean have same names right? In my model had 5 layers, I wanted to add a new layer in between. so I named the layers in new model same as the old one model and gave a new name to the new layer. Now my model has 6 layers. with the new layer in the middle. The above solution still works even if the order of layers is changed but the names are the same?

Answer (score 37):

This call:

```
weights_list = model.get_weights()
```

will return a list of all weight tensors in the model, as Numpy arrays.

All what you have to do next is to iterate over this list and apply:

```
for i, weights in enumerate(weights_list[0:9]):
    model.layers[i].set_weights(weights)
```

where `model.layers` is a flattened list of the layers comprising the model. In this case, you reload the weights of the first 9 layers.

More information is available here:

https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/

https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/

Comment: But this creates an even bigger issue. I'll have to define/compile both models and iterate through the layers to copy the weights. It's less readable and computationally worse than the code in the question. What I really want is a way to load the weights without loading the model so that I can set just the ones I want without having to define both models.

Comment: @Philippe if I do this for layers 2 to 9 (layer 1 is the input layer) because I changed the input size (concatenated 11 video frames rather than 3), how can I intialize the first layer?  I have weights but would need to expand the dim from 9 (3 * RGB) to 33 (11 *RGB) and then load them.