# Keras model weights organization for merged layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to save and load the weights of my model which has merged layer. Since my model code is bit long, let me shorten it by using a simple example and pseudo-style code.

First, my model looks like this:

```
def some_model():
  model1 = Sequential()
  model1.add(...)

  model2 = Sequential()
  model2.add(..)

  final_model = Sequential()
  final_model.add(Merge[model1, model2], mode='concat')

  return final_model
```

So, after the training, I only saved final_mode's weight.

```
final_model.save_weights('w_final_model.h5')
```

And it had no problem when I load the weight for further training or testing.

```
final_model = some_model()
final_model.load_weights('w_final_model.h5')
```

So far so good. Yet, my curiosity comes when I tried to investigate the shape of the final_model's layers.

Obviously, the final_model only has its own layers. In other words, it doesn't look carrying all the weights vectors of model1 and model2. But, it still works. I wonder how this can be possible. Or, is it only loading the weights for the final_model layers while the model1 and model2 weights are initialized again? Yet, the network's output is too good to assume that model1 and model2 weights are newly initialized. Indeed, do I need to save each model's weight separately?

Comment: When saving weights/model - `keras` is saving all weights/tensors involved in model computations. So your `final_model` saves also weights of `model_1` and `model_2` respectively.

Comment: @user9200689 - I have a similar question which I have put up here `https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37341/how-to-combine-two-deep-learning-model-weights-into-one/37347#37347` - only difference is for certain unavoidable reasons I am looking for combining weights of 2 models and make one new model. If you have any idea about it could you please throw some light into it?

Comment: @Jazz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702323/how-to-load-only-specific-weights-on-keras Probably you can load each layer manually to the new model's layers..?