# Delete some neurons at output layer (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm using Keras to make a GAN for synthetic data generating. So, i want use a pre-treined classifier model to be the Discriminator (Because I would not have to train the discriminator, only the generator).

The pre-treined model was made in keras and has originaly 4 outputs at last layer `Dense(4, activation='softmax')` (A, B, C, D). I'want generate synthetic data from class C. The Discriminator model must have only 1 output (fake or true),  so I need change the last layer from pre-treinade model to be only the C output. So, how i can do it in keras or maybe using Tensorflow at backend?

I'm looking something like this...

[image]

```
model = load_model('pre_treined_model.h5')
discriminator = model
discriminator.layers[-1] = "only C weight/output"
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702323/how-to-load-only-specific-weights-on-keras

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do something like this:

```
model = load_model('pre_trained_model.h5')
model.layers.pop()

x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model.layers[-1].output)
model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=[x])
```